# property-value database model

Tags: database-design

How to model a database when you have a different type of value(int, float, boolean, string etc.) of some property, and all possible types are not predefined? I think of a way that all values are strings in database and have some type attribute associated and then convert to that type in the application.. is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an alternative to a relational database.

A [document database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) such a [couch DB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [Raven DB](http://ravendb.net/) will give you the flexibility to store any type of data structure.

Comment: Interesting.. but I don't have knowledge about document databases.. anyway I'll see how to use them(doesn't look so scary :).. ty